# extend 'call hierarchy' in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, call-hierarchy

Is there any way to extend the tree, that is generated by the 'call hierarchy plugin'?  After a first look I did not find one.

background:
I would like to add some xml-parsing to find references on constants of some special classes.

Comment: you mean the call hierarchy shows you in which xml files the constant is being used?

Comment: Yes. I already implemented that code weeks ago and using it directly in that view would be very cool.

Comment: i don't think it is possible to include non-java sources in this view (at least not easy). best workaround is to use the search and enter the constants name. it will list you .xml files as well